# Integration as limit of sums

Tags: definite-integrals, area

Let $f\left(\frac xy\right)=\frac {f(x)}{f(y)}$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose $f'(1)$ exists. The area under curve $f(x)$ bounded by the $x$-axis, $x=0$ and $x=1$ is $\frac 13$.

Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\sum_{i=0}^n e^\frac in f\left(\frac{\sqrt{i}}{n}\right)$$

This was a 12th standard test question. 
The answer key tells $1$.

Comment: I tried it but could not get any answer

Comment: Show your working. Substitute $f(x)/f(y)$ for $f(\sqrt{i}/n)$ for starters. However, from your question it's not clear what $f(x/y)$ is equal to... what does $f(x)/f(y)\nabla x,y\in\mathfrak{R}$ mean? Perhaps this needs clarifying.

Comment: That statement is valid for all real values of x and y

Comment: Better to say "for all", or use $\forall$ then... and I would suggest using $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathfrak{R}$... I've updated the question...

Comment: What is $r$ in your statment ?

Comment: Sorry that was meant to be i

Comment: I think the first information you give can tell us a lot about $f$, taking $x=0$, this looks like a Riemann sum

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/305450/321264) answer for solving the functional equation. What you have to evaluate looks like a Riemann sum and you are also given that $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{3}$.